# How to simplify conditional probability of union of several events

Tags: pr.probability, problem-solving

I have an output binary scalar, $y∈B=\{0,1\}$, and an input binary vector $x=[x_1, x_2,…x_M]$ where $x_i∈B=\{0,1\}$. I know that the output $P(y)=1$ depends entirely on the input x. Thus, I want to simplify the expression:

$
Eq.1:
P(y|x_1∩x_2∩…x_M) 
$

I know 2 quantities:

$
Eq. 2a: 
P(y|x_i)      
$

$
Eq. 2b:
P(y|x_i∩x_j)
$

For all i & j

Furthermore, I can make 2 assumptions:

1. The input, x, is a ‘white’ / Poisson process. Ie, $x_i$ and $x_j $ are uncorrelated for all $i\neq j$.
2. The output y is dependent only on 1st and 2nd order statistics of the inputs shown in eq. 2a,b. Ie, single pulses and pairs of pulses affect y, while triplets of input pulses have no effect on y. I am not sure what the exact mathematical term for this is...

Thus, my question is  can I use the above knowledge and assumptions to simplify equation 1 and hopefully solve for it, preferably in terms of the 1st and 2nd order quantities

Comment: When you say a binary variable is in $[0,1]$, do you mean the set containing $0$ and $1$ rather than the interval from $0$ to $1$? Also, why is this tagged "open-problem?"

Comment: Hi Douglas, yes, I mean the set of 0 & 1: {0,1}. I edited accordingly. Also, open-problems was incorrect :-)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "triplets of input pulses have no effect on $y$?"

Comment: I mean that there are no 3rd order correlations of the input which affect the output. Thus, the effect of a spike triplet can be entirely described in terms of 3 spike pairs & 3 signle spikes. Did I answer you ok?